# Unable to launch a Spring web flow 2.3.1 (Spring 3.2.0 + JSF 2.0)

Tags: spring-webflow-2

I am unable to launch flow with Spring web flow 2.3.1 + Spring 3.2.0 + JSF 2.0. Spring is getting initialized, but when I am trying to load my flow, nothing happens.

I have attached a FlowExecutionListener, it get created. But no control is returned to it. Same way I am trying to get RequestContextHolder.getRequestContext(), it returns null.

I am not sure what is wrong with configuration. I tried all steps mentioned in configuration.

I am using below classes,

navigation handler - org.springframework.web.jsf.DelegatingNavigationHandlerProxy
variable-resolver - org.springframework.faces.webflow.SpringBeanWebFlowVariableResolver

I have custom ContextLoadListener, which get invoked. I am passing the webflow config xml as contextConfigLocation parameter to load. The file is also getting load as I have registered the FlowExecutionListener into it.